# Shared memory between threads

Tags: c, shared-memory

I am looking for C program source code. Could you please help me in finding the source code required mentioned below.

program to create multiple threads (one master thread and rest worker threads) and using the threads write into and read from shared memory.

Comment: What did you try? Where are you stuck? There are tons of information available in the internet on thread creation and shared memory usage on the various platforms.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Your question is a 'gimme the code' question, but such questions are not encouraged on SO.  Please read the [FAQ]. You're expected to have shown some effort in answering, and to ask about the details of the problem you're encountering.  It is also a good idea to mention the platform; the answer for a Unix-like system is different from the answer for a Windows-like system (and probably different again for Android or iOS).  For controlled access to shared memory, your synchronization mechanism is probably the crucial decision; the threads all share the same memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All the global variables are shared memory area for thread. 'x'  is global and share among all threads in following example.

```
#include<pthread.h>
#include<stdio.h> 
int sharedx=0;
void *threadFunc(void *arg)
{
    printf(" %d %s", sharedx,(char*)arg);
    sharedx++;
}
int main(void)
{
    pthread_t pth[10];  // this is our thread identifier
    int i = 0;
    for(i; i<10; i++) {  
       pthread_create(&pth[i],NULL,threadFunc,"processing...");
    }
}
```